# JSON is not appended after I get the response from the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get an array of json from my web-service page which works fine alone. My problem is after I make the ajax request, the json data is not appended.

this is the web-service.php page

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses";
    $num_of_rows = mysqli_query($db, $q);
    $number = mysqli_fetch_array($num_of_rows);

    $counter = 0;
    print('{"lenght":"');
    print $number['COUNT(*)'];
    print('",');
    print('"data":[');
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo json_encode($row);
      if ($counter === ($number['COUNT(*)'] - 1)) { } else {
        print(",");
      }
      $counter++;
    }
    print("]}");
```

this is the ajax request in home.js

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       $("#courses").append(json);        
     } else {
       console.log("readyState "+this.readyState);
       console.log("status "+this.status);
     }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "./web-service.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

the console shows this

```
    readyState 1         home.js:35:9
    status 0             home.js:36:9
    readyState 2         home.js:35:9
    status 200           home.js:36:9
    readyState 3         home.js:35:9
    status 200           home.js:36:9
```

Comment: Did you check the network tab in your browser Developer Tools? That may give you more information about this request...

Comment: Yes, that section shows the response but the readyState is still not 4. So the if statement will not become true to use the response. @BrunoMonteiro

Comment: if both the ready state is 4 and the status is 200, it won't show in the console, as the console log is only in the 'else' part of your if statement. Put a console log in the first part also and then you may see when the readyState reaches 4. Is it appending the json?

Comment: @RachelGallen that is true, it reached 4, but it is not appending the json. That is why  I thought it is not reaching. Any idea why id doesn't append the json?

Comment: @HawkarShwany then I'd examine your php closely. Check your ``mysqli_query`` and $row (no definition seems to be given for this). Ensure all vars are declared

Comment: @HawkarShwany my suggestion about the network tab was to also check the response body there...if your json is showing up there, then the issue is in the Javascript side. If the json is not showing there, then the issue is in the PHP side. That will help you narrow the problem :)

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro thank you the problem was from the Javascript side. The json shows up in the network tab but it is not appended in the jquery. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Sure! Try to console.log your `JSON.parse(this.responseText);` to see what is happening. I suspect the issue is with the content itself, not the `append` part.

Comment: Try this:  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);    replace "this" with the object "xhttp" ==>   var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

Comment: Thanks everyone. the problem was in this line $("#courses").append(json); I had to write json.data